# How t spawn objects from random places one at a time?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am making an android game for which i need to spawn items from top. I want the spawn places to be horizontally random at the top of my scene. I used these codes which is not giving me anything random and also multiple game objects spawns at same time from same spawner. I want to spawn a single game object at a time and the oher should only spawn after the first one destroyed from the game scene. Plz help me iam new to unity as well as c# and also Stackoverflow.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] spawnableItems;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        bool isTimeToSpawn (GameObject itemGameObject)
        {
            spawnableSprites item = itemGameObject.GetComponent<spawnableSprites>();
            float spawnDelay = item.seenEverySeconds;
            float spawnsPerSecond = 1 / spawnDelay;

            if(Time.deltaTime > spawnDelay)
            {
                Debug.LogWarning("SpawnRate Capped By FrameRate");
            }
            float threshold = spawnsPerSecond * Time.deltaTime;

            if(Random.value < threshold)
            {
                return true;
            }

            else
            {
                return false;
            }

        }


        foreach (GameObject item in spawnableItems)
        {
            if(isTimeToSpawn(item))
            {
                Spawn(item);
            }
        }
    }

    void Spawn (GameObject myGameObject)
    {
        GameObject myItem = Instantiate(myGameObject) as GameObject;
        myItem.transform.parent = transform;
        myItem.transform.position = transform.position;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to randomly spawn one object on top, and then spawn another only after the first one is destroyed? right?
Looks like you didn't need to spawn/delete multiple object.
You know in game dev we try to be as efficient as possible, sometimes all you need is to use an old object as a new one, and just trick the player to think it's new.
So my suggestion is that instead of deleting your object, just set it's position on top again, something like this:

```
float spawnXmin = 0;
float spawnXmax = 100;
float spawnY = 0;
float spawnZ = 0; // * numbers are just for demonstration
myItem.transform.position = new Vector3(Random.Range(spawnXmin, spawnXmax), spawnY, spawnZ);
```

Also do not use those code in Update(), anything you put in Update will cost you a lot, cause it will run in every frames, so avoid putting stuff in Update() as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
 void Start()
{
    // will wait 2 seconds then call the function Spawn() every 0.3 seconds
    InvokeRepeating("Spawn", 2.0f, 0.3f);
}

void Spawn()
{
    GameObject myItem = Instantiate(myGameObject) as GameObject;
    myItem.transform.parent = transform;
    myItem.transform.position = new Vector2(Random.Range(0, width) , height);
}
```

Comment: i did as you suggested and also tried not to put anything in update method. Now when i play the game it says "Trying to Invoke method: Spawner.Spawn couldn't be called." I don't know whats wrong now.